# Is it possible to make an NSString with some characters as subscripts and superscripts?

Tags: objective-c, text, nsstring

My app will have chemistry formulas (CO3^2-, H2O, etc), so some of the text in my app will need to have subscripts and superscripts. Is it possible to do this with NSStrings, or is there an alternative/easier way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [NSAttributedString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I need the text to be inside a UILabel and I read that NSAttributedStrings can't be used with UILabels. Is there any other way?

Comment: FYI, as of iOS 6 `NSAttributedString`s **can** be used with `UILabel`s.